# jQuery .each() function with ES6 arrow functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have this ES6 code, after I compile it with Babel to ES5 the `this` inside `.each`'s call back becomes `undefined`. How do I fix this problem?

```
let mediaBoxes = $(".now-thumbnail");
let titles = [];
mediaBoxes.each(() => {
      let obj = {
              index: i,
              title: $(this).find(".now-thumbnail-bottomtext").text().trim()
           };
  titles.push(obj);
});
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

My solution is to not use `this` at all, but use the variables that are passed to the callback function. The first one is the index and the second one gives you the DOM element itself.

```js
let mediaBoxes = $('.now-thumbnail');
let titles = [];
mediaBoxes.each((index, element) => {
  let obj = {
    index: index,
    title: $(element).find('.now-thumbnail-bottomtext').text().trim(),
  };
  titles.push(obj);
});
```

Answer (score 43):

That is because the mean of `this` is not the same in arrow functions.

[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this)

> Arrow functions capture the this value of the enclosing context,

The [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each) function passes the element as the second argument to the callback.

But a more appropriate solution for you will be to also use [.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map) instead of [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each)

```
let mediaBoxes = $(".now-thumbnail");
let titles = mediaBoxes.map((i, el) => {
  return {
    index: i,
    title: $(el).find(".now-thumbnail-bottomtext").text().trim()
  };
}).get();
```

Comment: I was thinking the same. `let titles = $('.now-thumbnail').map((index, element) => ({
    index: index,
    title: $(element).find(".now-thumbnail-bottomtext").text().trim()
})).get();`

Comment: @Tushar if the content is too big then I like to break it into a block

Comment: I'd also add that _there is no need of arrow functions here just for concise syntax and nothing is being returned. Anonymous functions can be used where `$(this)` will point to correct element_.

Comment: @Tushar I'd upvote that answer in a heartbeat. I see absolutely no benefit to an arrow here. Even if terseness is the goal, writing `function()` is exactly the same number of characters as `(i, el) =>`