# Using a Lodash collection function on jquery elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash

I'm trying to use lodash's `_.partition` on a jQuery collection of elements, like so:

```
const $elements = $('<div class="outer"><div class="thisOne">thisOne</div><div>not thisOne</div><div>nor thisOne</div></div>').children();
// the above line ends up printing {0: <div class="thisOne">thisOne</div>, 1: <div>not thisOne</div>, 2:<div>nor thisOne</div>, length: 3} I may have mis-rememebered how it gets there.
// regardless it's a list of $jQuery elements
const [$matched, $unmatched] = _.partition($elements, element => element.text() === "thisOne");

$matched.forEach(element => expect(element).toHaveClass("thisOne"));
$unmatched.forEach(element => expect(element).not.toHaveClass("thisOne"));
```

But my error is on the second line, where it says that  `element.text()` is not a function.

I've seen this question [jQuery .each() function with ES6 arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36638002/1075247) and I don't think it counts as this isn't a jQuery array function like `each`, and should just opperate on each element. Changing it to `(index, element) => element.text() === "thisOne"` still doesn't work, so I can't think that's the reason at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the result of `_.partition($elements, element => element.text() === "thisOne")` is that element is ***not*** a jQuery element, but a native dom element.

To correct this, you need to apply `$(...)` around element like so:

```
element => $(element).text()
```

That makes sure that each element is jQuery aware, before running jQuery function on it.

Comment: Why did I figure this out moments after posting my question?

Comment: element.textContent === "thisOne"

Comment: @gaetanoM I'll give that a go when I'm next able.